# Jmeter error when trying to create file using beanshell

Tags: jmeter

This is my beanshell code to create a file and append one line to it:

```
FileName = vars.get("fileName");

f = new FileOutputStream(FileName,true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 


print("Test Set: " + FileName);

f.close();
```

I get fileName from a regex extractor in a previous sampler. I have checked debug postprocessor and confirmed this is set correctly. However I get this error in sampler result:

```
Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh     method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``FileName = vars.get("fileName");  f = new FileOutputStream(FileNam . . . '' : Object constructor
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to use things like "String FileName = vars.get..."

Comment: I have tried declaring it as a string as you said, but that has not resolved the issue

Comment: Do you have proper declartions for f and p?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: if `FileName` is null, the constructor for `FileOutputStream` will throw an exception, and BeanShell is not great in showing underlying exceptions. So what you need is to handle the case where file name is null:

```
String fileName = vars.get("fileName");

if( fileName == null )
{
    fileName = "mydefaultname"; // assign some default name
}

f = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 


print("Test Set: " + fileName);

f.close();
```

If you don't want to have some default name, you can also quit the script at that point:

```
if( fileName == null )
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: So I tried this, and I get the same error:

'Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``FileName = vars.get("fileName");  if(FileName == null) . . . '' : Object constructor'

Comment: if you just copy/paste the script I suggested as a whole, does it work? (because I think the first line is also a problem, as suggested in earlier comment).